# Uploading Large size File (in chunks) on Sharepoint using Web Services

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I want to upload upload up to 100 MB to 1GB file onto sharepoint using Web Services ( C#).
Which can only possible by passing file data into chunks.

Regards,

Jene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code : http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/10/upload-file-to-sharepoint-document.html